Automatic upgrade to 24.04.1
I got a popup prompt to upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04.1. Will an auto-upgrade carry over the files, apps, and settings I'm using now? Or do I need to save my Home directory to an external drive and then manually install everything on the new system? Or something else? I'm not very proficient at tech stuff, and would prefer an easy method, but maybe not if that entails a compromise with reliability. Thanks in advance for any help.

It should preserve all your personal files and stuff. I would recommend following guide here or basically any upgrade guide.

A release-upgrade is not a simple process; so I'd always upgrade the system PRIOR to attempting any release-upgrade.  You didn't say if you're using a Server or Desktop system, but I'll suggest reading the release notes of the release you're going to first (https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-24-04-lts-noble-numbat-release-notes/39890) and especially all that applies to you, then read the upgrade instructions (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NobleUpgrades) and whatever else applies (this will vary on what you have installed as to what I'd suggest.. you only mentioned release details)

before proceeding (if that becomes your plan) consider using something like Timeshift to make a complete backup of your existing system in case you decide (given many of the issues reported on AU) you'd like to go back to your present arrangement.

Sorry my wording wasn't ideal in a prior comment;  I intended "A release-upgrade is not a simple process; so I'd always BACKUP the system PRIOR to attempting any release-upgrade..."   ie. yes upgrade is required first, but I was trying to stress BACKUP first & I omitted that word sorry !!  (upgrade isn't critical/important, as system will check & tell you to apply all upgrades before you can release-upgrade anyway.. I didn't intention mentioning that.. just BACKUP!!)

@guiverc, After several attempts I've apparently upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04.1  So far, I don't see any difference from 22.04. In Settings>About, I see Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, 64-bit, Gnome 42.9, and Wayland. I read that I would have Gnome 46. Is there something wrong? Have I failed to do a full upgrade? Or is it supposed to look the same until I make changes? I'm confused but hopeful.

You've provided no clues as to what you're referring to in regards version. https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-24-04-lts-noble-numbat-release-notes/39890 and other docs will tell you what you should have, but are you going by some detail on screen as if its from a wallpaper it means nothing. If going by package versions, contrast with the manifest or what you'd have on a new install, or use CLI enquiry. I don't know where you're getting 42.9 from as you don't specify so I don't know what that 42.9 represents. eg. I'm not on noble, but gnome-shell --version tells me GNOME Shell 47.0

A system that is release-upgraded will keep most defaults from the prior release (many of which were set by install media; however long ago that was) so the system can be expected to look different to a fresh install (most users won't their system to upgrade & not look/act that differently; just newer software). As we're limited to details you provide, its helpful if you're specific as to what exactly you mean & where from when you say 42.9; the release-upgrade intentionally doesn't touch wallpaper settings as example; even a non-destructive re-install won't do that either.

@guiverc I went to discourse.ubuntu.com/t/… and read that this release has Gnome 46. The terminal tells me I have gnome-shell --version 42.9. Thunderbird Mail is now 115.15 which was released on Sep. 5. I think this is different from what I had before. Should I do something to get Gnome 46, or is that something out of my control? Thank you for your patience.

I'd likely explore your system directly... Firstly I'd examine your sources; ie. all are correct for a Ubuntu system, none missing etc, and you're using an official Ubuntu mirror. Next I'd explore the packages, eg. your last comment mentions gnome-shell you used to explore; so apt policy gnome-shell; my own result shows in it the package installed & source, ie. package version 47.0-1ubuntu2 from source http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oracular/main which fits what I'm running..  Does yours... etc.  I'd sudo apt update & assuming all good detail show, sudo apt full-upgrade

If you're not familiar with checking apt update output and can't pick if missing detail is there, just examine your sources, ie. /etc/apt/sources.list and also what's in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ (esp. /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources which may contain what used to be /etc/apt/sources.list but ensure you have correct details in one!)

@guiverc I'm not familiar with anything in the terminal. When I ran those sources lists I got invalid operations errors. I am once more running full-upgrade. This time I'm told they are waiting for cache locks that are. held  by process 17306. I don't know what that means. Should I leave the computer on while continuing to wait, or should I just exit that terminal?

The files I mentioned in the /etc/apt/ directory are files; you can cat them, or view them in whatever tools you're familiar with; if you're not familiar with terminal commands (any POSIX/unix/linux) it'll be more difficult (microsoft DOS is a mix of unix & CP/M commands; microsoft windows is thus similar but not identical due to CP/M influence of prior DOS product by microsoft; MS failing to sell xenix or their unix OS to IBM back in early 80s)..  the LOCK error  means you have another command executing in another window, or just normal [background] update running when you tried....
